# keeping a batch program up

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

Background: I'm using a public computer running windows 7. I don't have permissions to access to the command line (nor the control panel, nor most of C drive). So, I've written the commands I need to execute as a batch program and saved it in a file called "run.bat" onto the Desktop. I run the program by double-clicking the batch file's icon. Something goes wrong, but I can't see what the problem is since as soon at the error comes up the command line disappears. This happens extremely quickly, so I can't even take a screen shot to see the error message.

I've encountered this problem before with batch programs crashing and then disappearing. Is there a way to keep the command line up after an error occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the command ['pause'](http://www.computerhope.com/pausehlp.htm) as the last line in the batch file. If you want to get fancy, only execute that line if you detect an error (in whatever you're doing in the batch file).